# How to change the height BETWEEN sections in GROUPED UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios

The default height is too large for me.
How can I change the height between two sections?

============================================================================

Sorry for my poor English...
I mean the gap between two sections is too large. How to change it?

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 2.0f);
    UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return view;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 2.0f);
    UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return view;
}
```

I changed the header view and footer view of each section.
And here is the result:
[image]

I think there may be a min height of the gap, because I set the height of header and footer to 2px, but the gap between two sections is still so large.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, do you mean make the gap between two sections smaller, or change the height of one section while the other section remains the same size?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. I mean the gap between two sections.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use footer views between each of your sections and give them the size of the space you desire by implementing the following methods in your UITableView's delegate.

`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`

In the first delegate method you can return a simple UIView instance, and in the second you can return the height that this view should be. This second delegate method should allow you to control the gap between sections.

Comment: Yes, I think there is a minimum distance. Thank you:)

Comment: The tableFooterView property does not refer to footer views between sections.

Comment: That's true. The tableFooterView is a view which is placed at the very bottom of the UITableView. The footer views for each section can be provided by the delegate using the `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section` method. I've updated by answer with this correction. Thanks.

Comment: if you want to make the height zero, remember NOT to return 0 but a value slightly larger than 0, say 0.000001f

Comment: What if I already have section headers and I need to decrease the distance between them?

Answer (score 8):

On iOS 15 you can change the section header top padding

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
}
```

Comment: saved my day thank you!! this fixed it for me

Answer (score 4):

try out this code

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = 0; // in viewdidload
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone]; //    in viewdidload

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.01f;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return <your header height>;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return <your header view>;
}
```

and the Swift version is

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,  viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return your footer view
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return your footer view height
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.01
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return UIView.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Edit:

Instead of `CGFLOAT_MIN` you should use **`CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude`**

---

You need to use method heightForHeaderInSection for defining space between header & cell text. You can also change it depending on different sections for eg. at some sections you may need to show more distance & under some, you don't want to show gap. For such case you can use

> `CGFLOAT_MIN` which is `0.000001f`

. Giving you an example, how you can use different section with different header heights

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0 || section == 2)
    {
        return 55.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return CGFLOAT_MIN;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to **increase** the distance.

The solutions based on setting header/footer height can have one side effect: if you have some text for you header or footer, it will be centered vertically inside your increased header/footer.

To solve this you can use a custom header/footer view, but I would suggest adding an empty section where you need additional gap and setting footer height for it (set " " as the footer text, in case of nil or an empty string it won't be displayed).

Comment: What if I already have section headers and I need to decrease the distance between them?